# When writing a test for Flutter, what happens when similar aspects appear more than one time? How to filter for the right one?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-test

I'm writing unit and integration tests for Flutter. If many widgets, with similar aspects (e.g. text), appear more than one time, how to filter for the right one?

Answer (score 2):

There are several options:

- [`Finder.first`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/flutter_test/Finder/first.html) finds the first occurrence of the widget
- [`Finder.last`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/flutter_test/Finder/last.html) finds the last occurrence of the widget
- [`Finder.hitTestable`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/flutter_test/Finder/hitTestable.html) finds only the widgets that can be reached by a hit test (e.g. by a tap)
- [`Finder.skipOffstage`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/flutter_test/Finder/skipOffstage.html) finds only widgets considered to be "on-stage" (see [Offstage](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Offstage-class.html) widget)
- [`find.descendant`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/flutter_test/CommonFinders/descendant.html) finds only widgets that are descendants of another widget

Finally you can use [`find.byPredicate`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/flutter_test/CommonFinders/byWidgetPredicate.html) or even extend the [`Finder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/flutter_test/Finder-class.html) class and get much more flexibility.

Comment: For code usage of `find.descendant`, please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47296248/190309